# Redefining .push() with Object.defineProperty that returns array

Tags: javascript, prototype, defineproperty

If I have a property on an object created by calling `Object.defineProperty` on the prototype of its constructor function that returns an array such as:

```
function Foo() { 
    this._bar = []; 
}

Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'bar', { 
    get: function () { 
        return this._bar; 
    }
});
```

How can I capture and override calls to `.push()` on the derived `bar`property?

Comment: Your getter doesn't even work, it needs to be `return this._bar`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to detect `foo.bar.push()` calls, but not `foo._bar.push()` ones?

Comment: Why do you want to do that at all? Are you looking to make your "private" array immutable?

Comment: Sorry the getter issue was a typo. Yes, I was to detect ``foo.bar.push()`` not ``foo._bar.push()`` calls.

Comment: And what about `foo.bar[foo.bar.length] = 1`? `push`ing is not the only means of appending to an array. What do you want to capture in general, and what do you need to overwrite?

Comment: I am trying to add to a set of objects that has some lower-level representation. I was wondering if I could coopt ``Array.prototype.push`` to implement this abstraction.

Comment: I would recommend to rather use a `Foo.prototype.push` method for that. The `.bar` getter would only return copies (using `.slice()`) of `_bar` so that the lower-level representation cannot be compromised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a full, working example of how you can override `push` on your property.

```
function Foo() { 
    this._bar = []; 
    var oldPush = this._bar.push;
    this._bar.push = function(){

        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
            //do something with each element if needed
            $('body').append("<p>INSERTING VALUE: " + arguments[i] + "</p>");
        }

        oldPush.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'bar', { 
    get: function () { 
        return this._bar; 
    }
});
```

Check this out for a demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppatino/5yfhr3ns/)

**UPDATE:** Edited the code to be able to call push with a list of params, e.g. `foo.bar.push(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Good, but do not forget: `var a = new Foo(); a._bar = [1,2];` will replace _bar and _bar.push.

Comment: Notice that `foo.bar.push(1, 2)` doesn't work with this example.

Comment: @Bergi - Nice.  I udpated the code to be able to `push` as you described (`foo.bar.push(1, 2)`)